# Previously published puzzles where provided answers appear to be incorrect or the puzzle appears to be unsolvable

Tags: discussion

Puzzles available online or in books often come with provided answers that are unsatisfactory in some way. The social aspect of Puzzling SE means it provides a good home for such questions to be re-asked ([with correct attribution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)) if the published solution was unhelpfully terse, or worse, a multiple-choice answer only. The question asker here knows what the answer "should" be, can ask for particular attention to be given to the part they felt they didn't "get", and can reward (upvoting, green-ticking or even bounty-awarding) whatever answer provides the most illuminating explanation.

But what about cases where the published answer appears to be wrong — or suggests a lapse in logic during the construction of the puzzle, which may render it unsolvable? It's clearly important to acknowledge the possibility of the published answer being incorrect, or the puzzle unsolvable, when posting the puzzle as a a question here. What's less clear is:

- Should the OP provide, again with appropriate attribution, the published solution? If so, where? Should it be posted as part of the question, as a hint to the question, or (I think not, but it would have a certain logic) even posted as a self-answer to the question?
- Should the OP comment on what seems to be wrong with the published question and solution? If so, where?
- Should the OP go further, and provide their own attempt at a solution, or a "proof" as to why no solution is possible? If so, where?
- If the question receives conflicting answers — perhaps some agree with the provided answer and some do not — how is the OP to judge who's correct, given they suspect the published answer may not be definitive? (Role here for community input, via comments and up/down-voting.)

---

I've kept the above general, as that often makes Meta questions more helpful in the longer term, but obviously it's triggered by a particular example: *False Logic Puzzles* by Norman D. Willis (Sterling Publishing Company, 1997, ISBN: 978-0806998046). This book extends those "[some islanders are truth-tellers, but the rest are liars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/truth-tellers-and-liars/)" logic puzzles beloved of everyone from [Epimenides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimenides_paradox) some 2600 years ago, to [Math Olympiad selection test writers](https://parallel.org.uk/10-30-ignobel-prize#:%7E:text=Alex%2C%20Beatrice%2C%20Charmian%20and%20Denzil%20are%20four%20children.%20Each%20of%20them%20either%20always%20tells%20the%20truth%20or%20always%20tells%20lies) today. It introduces further "standards of veracity", such as people who lie or speak truthfully in alternating statements, or who lie at random, or depending on the time of day, or even depending on the veracity standard of the person they are talking about. All good clean logical fun, until doubts start to sink in about some of the answers.

Much of the book is well done, with some entertaining puzzles. The wording is frustratingly sloppy at times — sometimes it's necessary to check the answers just to see how the question was supposed to be interpreted — but I could tighten up or reword those elements if reposting here. More troubling is what looks like sloppy logic in some of the solutions, for example apparently unjustified inferences. Then again, maybe my brain's just turned to mush while trying to reason out "if it's the morning, how can C be lying about A lying about B lying about what time of the day A lies?" (A genuine example by the way.) It doesn't seem to be a well-known book but a few online reviews like "I couldn't work out the answer to some of these" suggest I'm not alone in my confusion. If any of the Brains Trust here happen to know Willis's work (he was a prolific puzzle author, but [has only once been referenced on this site before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=willis)), you might advise me how likely the error is to be on my part or the writer's.

Having perused the answers to ["unsolvable puzzles"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6724/unsolvable-puzzles) on Meta, I can see one option that would let me salvage a solvable question from an apparently unsolvable one (without losing anything if it turns out the mistake is mine) would be to rephrase questions like "Which of A, B, and C are truth-tellers and which are liars?" to "Which, if any, of A, B, and C can we determine to be truth-tellers or liars?" This way, even if some of the identities turn out to be ambiguous, we still have a meaningful question... unless the problem with the puzzle's construction is so severe that no combination of liars and truth-tellers could produce the given collection of statements, and I don't think I've seen any that bad yet.

Answer (score 1):

> - Should the OP provide, again with appropriate attribution, the published solution? If so, where? Should it be posted as part of the question, as a hint to the question, or (I think not, but it would have a certain logic) even posted as a self-answer to the question?

If OP was asking how this puzzle was meant to be solvable (work shown would be a big plus, but not required), then definitely as part of the question.

If OP was posting this to see if anyone else could solve it, then it probably shouldn't be posted as part of the question at all, however, if the steps needed to be taken would make more sense if it was posted as a hint, then that could give a bit more insight as to how it could be achieved.

However, as a self-answer? You are right in saying no. The published solution should most likely be omitted, but that is just my opinion.

---

> - Should the OP comment on what seems to be wrong with the published solution and question? If so, where?

If and only if they are stuck on a puzzle and they are showing their work that they have taken to make progress on the puzzle, and this should be a part of the question.

---

> - Should the OP go further, and provide their own attempt at a solution, or a "proof" as to why no solution is possible? If so, where?

Again, if and only if they are stuck on a puzzle and they show their work. Proofs are actually good as a part of the question if it ties into their work that they have done.

---

> - If the question receives conflicting answers — perhaps some agree with the provided answer and some do not — how is the OP to judge who's correct, given they suspect the published answer may not be definitive? (Role here for community input, via comments and up/down-voting.)

That's difficult. Maybe if work is shown, it'll be easier to understand why the published solution is correct/incorrect? With comments, maybe hints could be given by other users for the OP as to how to solve it? I'm also not exactly sure how up/down-voting would play into this.

---

If it is decided by the OP to reword the question, the original question and source material should be posted for reference, but the original answer I don't think so, because maybe the answer ended up changing when going through the solve process again, or maybe the answer ended up being the same.

---

However, this is just my opinion, so maybe someone else will come along and clarify some more stuff that I'm not exactly sure on.